# Build Boost for Windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-mobile, boost, windows-ce, bjam

Does anyone have a set of instructions for building boost libraries for use on Windows CE?  I've found some discussions on it:

[boost build mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2009/06/21997.php)

[and another one from the boost build mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2009/05/21822.php)

... but surely someone has written up something more concrete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There looks to be the [source for a batch file here](http://old.nabble.com/Building-Boost-for-Windows-CE-tt22541930.html#a23591291) that builds them for CE.

**EDIT**

I apologize for the long post, but in case the link goes dead again, here's the batch file:

```
    @SET VCINSTALLDIR=%VS9INSTALLDIR%\VC 
    @if "%VS9INSTALLDIR%"=="" goto error_no_VSINSTALLDIR 
    @if "%VCINSTALLDIR%"=="" goto error_no_VCINSTALLDIR 

    @echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 tools for WM5. 
    @set TARGETCPU=X86 

    @call :GetWindowsSdkDir 

    @if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" ( 
            set "PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin;%PATH%" 
    ) 

    @rem 
    @rem Root of Visual Studio IDE installed files. 
    @rem 
    @set DevEnvDir=%VS9INSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE 

    @set PATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%\CE\bin\x86_arm;%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin;%VS9INSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools;%DevEnvDir%;%VS9INSTALLDIR%\Common\Tools;%VS9INSTALLDIR%\Common\IDE;%VS9INSTALLDIR%;%PATH%
     @set INCLUDE=%STLPORT_PATH%\STLPort-5.2.1\stlport;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce\include;%CETOOLS%\Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK\include\ARMV4I;%CETOOLS%\Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK\include;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce\atlmfc\include
     @set LIB=%STLPORT_PATH%\STLPort-5.2.1\lib\evc9-arm;%CETOOLS%\Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK\lib\ARMV4I;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce\ATLMFC\LIB\ARMV4I;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ce\LIB\ARMV4I
     @set LIBPATH= 

    @goto end 

    :GetWindowsSdkDir 
    @call :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper HKLM > nul 2>&1 
    @if errorlevel 1 call :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper HKCU > nul 2>&1 
    @if errorlevel 1 set WindowsSdkDir=%VCINSTALLDIR%\PlatformSDK\ 
    @exit /B 0 

    :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper 
    @for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" /v "CurrentInstallFolder"') DO (
             if "%%i"=="CurrentInstallFolder" ( 
                    SET "WindowsSdkDir=%%k" 
            ) 
    ) 
    @if "%WindowsSdkDir%"=="" exit /B 1 
    @exit /B 0 


    :error_no_VSINSTALLDIR 
    @echo ERROR: VS9INSTALLDIR variable is not set. 
    @goto end 

    :error_no_VCINSTALLDIR 
    @echo ERROR: VCINSTALLDIR variable is not set. 
    @goto end 

    :end 

    @SET VCINSTALLDIR=%VS9INSTALLDIR%\VC 
    @SET FrameworkDir=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework 
    @SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727 
    @SET Framework35Version=v3.5 
    @if "%VS9INSTALLDIR%"=="" goto error_no_VSINSTALLDIR 
    @if "%VCINSTALLDIR%"=="" goto error_no_VCINSTALLDIR 

    @echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools with STLport-5.2.1.

    @call :GetWindowsSdkDir 

    @if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" ( 
            set "PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin;%PATH%" 
            set "INCLUDE=%WindowsSdkDir%include;%INCLUDE%" 
            set "LIB=%WindowsSdkDir%lib;%LIB%" 
    ) 


    @rem 
    @rem Root of Visual Studio IDE installed files. 
    @rem 
    @set DevEnvDir=%VS9INSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE 

    @set PATH=%DevEnvDir%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\BIN;%VS9INSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools;%FrameworkDir%\%Framework35Version%;%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\VCPackages;%PATH%
     @set INCLUDE=%STLPORT_PATH%\STLport-5.2.1\stlport;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;%VCINSTALLDIR%\INCLUDE;%INCLUDE%
     @set LIB=%STLPORT_PATH%\STLport-5.2.1\lib\vc9;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\LIB;%VCINSTALLDIR%\LIB;%LIB%
     @set LIBPATH=%FrameworkDir%\%Framework35Version%;%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\LIB;%VCINSTALLDIR%\LIB;%LIBPATH%

    @goto end 

    :GetWindowsSdkDir 
    @call :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper HKLM > nul 2>&1 
    @if errorlevel 1 call :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper HKCU > nul 2>&1 
    @if errorlevel 1 set WindowsSdkDir=%VCINSTALLDIR%\PlatformSDK\ 
    @exit /B 0 

    :GetWindowsSdkDirHelper 
    @for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" /v "CurrentInstallFolder"') DO (
             if "%%i"=="CurrentInstallFolder" ( 
                    SET "WindowsSdkDir=%%k" 
            ) 
    ) 
    @if "%WindowsSdkDir%"=="" exit /B 1 
    @exit /B 0 

    :error_no_VSINSTALLDIR 
    @echo ERROR: VSINSTALLDIR variable is not set. 
    @goto end 

    :error_no_VCINSTALLDIR 
    @echo ERROR: VCINSTALLDIR variable is not set. 
    @goto end 

    :end
```

Comment: Possible alternative link: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Building-Boost-for-Windows-CE-td2695528.html